# Custom string deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a custom string of data that I've never worked with before.  It appears to be similar to JSON, but it has a unique structure to it that I can't work out how to properly deserialize.

Here's an example string showing a simplistic mock-structure of what I'm dealing with:

```
description="
has_table=TRUE
scale=1.0
apply_scale=FALSE
custom_units=1
style{
 0{
  name="TestName1
  description="
  color=-1006632961
  size=0.5
  adaptive=TRUE
 }
 1{
  name="TestName2
  description="
  color=-1
  size=0.75
  adaptive=TRUE
 }
 2{
  name="TestName3
  description="
  color=-1006632354
  size=1.5
  adaptive=FALSE
 }
 size_table{
 0=0.0
 1=0.1
 2=0.2
 3=0.25
 10=0.35
 13=0.5
 17=0.75
 20=1.0
 21=1.25
 22=1.5
}
```

I've been manually rolling my own classes so far.  The above string would end up deserializing into the following classes:

```
public class ExampleStyleList
{
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public bool HasTable {get; set;}
    public double Scale {get; set;}
    public bool ApplyScale {get; set;}
    public int CustomUnits {get; set;}
    public IList<double> Sizes {get; set;}

    protected IList<ExampleStyle> InnerStyles {get; set;}
}

public class ExampleStyle
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public System.Drawing.Color Color {get; set;}
    public double Size {get; set;}
    public bool Adaptive {get; set;}
}
```

Right now I'm manually deserializing everything to my classes; reading a line at a time and looking for brackets, building dictionaries, and looking for static names for things.  It's pretty ugly, and can't be efficient, not to mention likely being super fragile.   I feel like I'd benefit from going from this weird format to XML first, to which I'd be able to just use an XMLSerializer, however I'm really drawing a blank.

Comment: to add on you class structure, i would also create a size_table class since it will link your sizes to an ID, instead of an ILIST of doubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just mimicking XML node hierarchy manually, and am pretty happy with the results.  Once I had set up my classes to inherit from the custom node class, implementing deserialization was pretty straightforward.  As we iterate through the lines, either we're adding a value to the current node, or we are building a child node.  Deserialization gets invoked from an internal constructor, so there's recursion here that may not be obvious at first glance.

```
    public static void Deserialize(PiaNode node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Node");

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerData))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("InnerData");

        var dataLines = node.InnerData.Split(new char[]{'\r', '\n'},
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataLines.Length; i++)
        {
            var curLine = dataLines[i];
            if (curLine.Contains('='))
            {
                var value = _getValue(curLine);

                if (!node.Values.ContainsKey(value.Key))
                    node.Values.Add(value.Key, value.Value);
                else
                    node.Values[value.Key] = value.Value;
            }
            else if (curLine.Contains('{'))
            {
                var bracketCount = 1;
                var nodeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                var n = i + 1;
                var subLine = string.Empty;

                while (bracketCount != 0)
                {
                    subLine = dataLines[n++];
                    bracketCount += subLine.Contains('{')
                        ? 1 : subLine.Contains('}')
                        ? -1 : 0;

                    if (bracketCount != 0)
                        nodeBuilder.AppendLine(subLine);
                }

                var childNode = new PiaNode(nodeBuilder.ToString())
                {
                    NodeName = curLine.Trim().TrimEnd('{'),
                    Parent = node
                };

                node.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
                i = n - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static KeyValuePair<string, string> _getValue(string valueString)
    {
        var prop = valueString.TrimEnd(new char[] {'\r', '\n'}).Split('=');
        return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(prop[0].Trim(), prop[1].TrimStart('\"'));
    }
```

Rather than try and set the properties of the node-inherited classes during deserialization (which I was doing before), I just linked the setters/getters of the properties straight to the dictionary that was populated during deserialization.